# Option to skip a section in R markdown (slides as output)

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I have an `ioslides_presentation` with multiple slides (say 20). Some of the slides are optional (say 10-14). I want to allow the user to skip those optional slides (option to move directly from slide 9 to slide 15). Is this possible without going through each of the intermediate slides?

**Edit**

I want the slide to open in same tab. However, the following markdown opens a new tab in R v3.3.0 and knitr v1.12.3:

`This is slide 5`

`[Go to slide 10](#/10)`

**Edit on edit**

The following code opens a new tab starting from title slide in R v3.3.0 and knitr v1.12.3:

`---`

`title: "Untitled"`

`output: ioslides_presentation`

`---`

`## R Markdown`

`[Go to slide 2](#/slide2)`

`## Slide with Bullets`

`id: slide2`

Comment: Are you looking for "internal links" on slides like [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200714013-Slide-Transitions-and-Navigation)? (subsection "Slide Links")

Comment: Yes. This idea works well, but opens a new tab that begins at the given slide number. Is it possible to open it in the same tab?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the new window/new tab issue, neither using Firefox nor in the RStudio Viewer. I suppose this is related to some settings on your system. Did you use an anchor as link target, like `#/slide1`?

Comment: Please check the latest edit for sample markdown. Effect: New tab opened starting with slide 10

Comment: You've got the syntax wrong in your example. You need to set an ID `id: myid` and use this a link target `#/myid`. Have you tried the example provided in the linked documentation chapter?

Comment: Please check edit on edit

Comment: Found an answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807477/hyperlinking-within-an-html-presentation-using-r-markdown