# Opening a link in the same tab with html

Tags: html

I want to open a link in the same tab with html when clicking a word. Nevertheless, even if I've tried it using `target="_self`" and not using any target, it only works with `target="_blank"`, but, as you may know, this opens the link in another tab.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
  min-width:360px;
}
a{
   color:#009900;
   text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover
{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
p
{
  font:0.8em sans-serif;
}
h1
{
  font:1.5em sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  background:#006600;
  padding:5px
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>play</h1>
 <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">YT player</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you just leave target blank or remove it? I think that will open the link in the same window/tab.

Comment: If I remove it the link doesn't open, I don't know why, but the only way in which I've managed to open the link is the one below.

Comment: It's probably because there is an error in your HTML code, I can see you're not closing the <p> tag. Thats probably it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```html
<a target="_self" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Use `_self`

```
<a target="_self" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Open link in the same tab

```
<a target="_self" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Adds a new tab EVERY TIME the link is clicked, and opens the link in it

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Creates a new tab ONLY ONCE, and opens the link in that SAME NEW tab that was created (not creating a new tab every time)

```
<a target="_new" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Creates a new tab ONLY ONCE and Opens the link in that same new tab (not creating a new tab every time, and opens the link in the specific tab that was created by its given ID. You can create multiple tabs with different IDs.)

```
<a target="myYTPlayerTab" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

In case the target attribute of the link matches the name of an iframe that is on the same page, the link will open in that iframe.

```
<a target="myYTPlayerIframe" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="myYTPlayerIframe" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

In case the user is inside a sub frame, it opens the link in the parent iframe

```
<a target="_parent" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

In case the user is in a frame with in a frame, it opens the link in the top iframe

```
<a target="_top" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com">YT-Player</a></p>
```

Comment: I have already tried that but the link won't open in my case, it just does't do anything when being clicked.

Comment: This works for you cause in your case the browser determines the actions. If you do not specify anything, then it goes by default or whatever the browser determines is the default.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure you might have figured it out by now (over a year later), but your code:

`<a target="_self" href="https://www.youtube.com" >YT player</a>`

is written a bit strange. Try:

`<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_self">YT player</a>`

Comment: No, order of attributes and extra whitespace around attributes makes no difference.